Should we use the brands properly in tags?
Should we use more generic tags?
Our tag technic assumes that all technic bricks are LEGO Technic.
Our tag clone-brands assumes that all but LEGO bricks are clones and does not allow to distinguish between the manufacturers.
How about a tag for each manufacturer and a neutral tag technical for the brick family?
Instead of the brand LEGO Technic in technic: A more advanced form of LEGO®, allowing for the creation of more realistic working parts.
we can use
technical: Bricks in form of gears, axles and mechanical parts.
And trains would allow to tag trains from any manufacturer.
Our users may combine them as in technical + cobi

Technic is also less about bricks these days, and more "beams with holes" ;)

Also TLG appear to have a trade mark on "Technic"  so that's actually the brand, similar to Duplo, etc., as opposed to "technical" which would be a generic term for the system.

@Zhaph-BenDuguid very good point. I will include this in my post.

There aren't so many "technical" questions for clone brands, so it would be fine without technical tag. While technic and building-techniques suit Technic and brick building related questions of relatively complex LEGO matter.
